# How to add onclick listener on cardview recylcerview which is fetched from firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an android application in which firestore database is used.The data is fetched in to a cardview in recylerview how can i set on click listener on card view to show detail information on next activity and also i can change data in realtime if needed.

Comment: My advice is to ask focussed questions. This is about 3 or 4 questions and very hard to answer on a site like this.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the OnClickListener on ViewHolder constructor.

```
MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        // Do something
    });
}
```